# Inner destructured property not received by ELK stack as destructured, but as escaped string

Tags: azure-service-fabric, elastic-stack, serilog, elk

I'm not sure if this is a Serilog, ELK, Service Fabric, code or config issue.

I am writing a Service Fabric Stateless Service. My logging configuration line is this:

```
            Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.EventFlow(loggingOptions.DiagnosticPipeline)
                .Destructure.With<JsonNetDestructuringPolicy>()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .CreateLogger()
                .ForContext(properties);
```

...where properties is an array of PropertyEnricher and the Policy is from [Destructurama's JsonNetDestructuringPolicy](https://github.com/destructurama/json-net/blob/dev/src/Destructurama.JsonNet/JsonNet/JsonNetDestructuringPolicy.cs).

I have a custom object base class that is successfully being destructured, so if I call it Data,  then in ELK's JSON tab I see:

```
"payload": {
  "Data": {
    "Property1": "Prop Value",
    "Property2": "Prop2 Value"
  }
}
```

However, when one of the inner objects is also destructured, it is sent as an escaped JSON string instead of being destructured, with no quotes around the property names:

```
"payload": {
  "Data": {
    "Property1": "Prop Value",
    "DestructuredProp": "{InnerProperty: \"Inner Value\"}"
  }
}
```

What I expected was:

```
"payload": {
  "Data": {
    "Property1": "Prop Value",
    "DestructuredProp": {
      "InnerProperty": "Inner Value"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know why the inner property names are not given quotes, or why the entire value is being escaped and quoted instead of destructured.
I have verified that my destructuring code is being executed. I can manually add quotes around the property name, for example, but it just results in more escaped quotes in the inner value.

My own code was destructuring it directly from C#. I thought it might have been a bug in my destructuring code, so I looked around some more and found [Destructurama's JsonNetDestructuringPolicy](https://github.com/destructurama/json-net/blob/dev/src/Destructurama.JsonNet/JsonNet/JsonNetDestructuringPolicy.cs), so I tried that, converting my object with JObject.fromObject(), but the same thing happens with it.

I'm pretty sure I should be able to do this with Serilog. I don't think there would be a depth limit setting if it couldn't do more than one layer deep. Why doesn't this work? I have tried refreshing the field index in Kibana, but the JSON view shows the escaped string, so I'm pretty sure it is being sent incorrectly, and isn't an ELK issue.

---EDIT---

Here is a destructuring policy I tried. My initial object is JsonEvent, and it has a Dictionary that is not destructuring, even though the Dictionayr policy is successfully being invoked.

```
    public class JsonEventDestructuringPolicy : IDestructuringPolicy
    {
        public bool TryDestructure(object value, ILogEventPropertyValueFactory propertyValueFactory, out LogEventPropertyValue result)
        {
            if (value is JsonEvent jsonEvent)
            {
                var properties = new List<LogEventProperty>();
                foreach (var property in value.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    var propertyValue = property.GetValue(value);
                    var isCollection = propertyValue is ICollection<Dictionary<string,string>>;
                    var isDictionary = propertyValue is Dictionary<string,string>;
                    if (isCollection)
                        LoggingContext.Message("Found collection of dictionary: " + property.Name);
                    else if (isDictionary)
                        LoggingContext.Message("Found dictionary: " + property.Name);
                    else if (property.Name.Equals("Parameters"))
                        LoggingContext.Message("Found Parameters: " + propertyValue.GetType());
                    if (propertyValue != null)
                        properties.Add(new LogEventProperty(property.Name, propertyValueFactory.CreatePropertyValue(propertyValue, isCollection || isDictionary)));
                }
                result = new StructureValue(properties);

                return true;
            }

            if (value is Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
            {
                var properties = new List<LogEventProperty>();
                foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(kvp.Value))
                        properties.Add(new LogEventProperty("\"" + kvp.Key + "\"", propertyValueFactory.CreatePropertyValue(kvp.Value)));
                }
                result = new StructureValue(properties);

                return true;
            }

            result = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It is being invoked like this:

```
        public static void Message(JsonEvent message)
        {
            Logger.ForContext(GetEnrichers(message))
                .Information(message.Event);
        }

        private static IEnumerable<ILogEventEnricher> GetEnrichers(JsonEvent message)
        {
            return new List<ILogEventEnricher>()
                .Add("Data", message, true)
                .Add("CorrelationId", ServiceTracingContext.CorrelationId)
                .Add("CorrelationDateTime", ServiceTracingContext.CorrelationDateTime)
                .Add("RouteTemplate", ServiceTracingContext.RouteTemplate)
                .ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: the thing you're expecting to be destructured, needs to be either configured in the config explicitly as "always destructure", or marked as `{@data}` - the default is not to descend into just every object

Comment: Sorry, I should have included what I had tried. Both my code and JsonNetDestructuringPolicy use `propertyValueFactory.CreatePropertyValue(value, true)`, so it is being told to destructure the value.

Comment: Further, I know that it WAS calling my destructure policy, because I altered it to add the quotes around the property names, thinking that ELK was messing it up because it wasn't valid JSON. So, the destructuring class is being called, and I manually created the destrucured data by creating a list of LogEventProperty myself and putting it in a StructureValue. However, that StructureValue is still turned into a single String.

Comment: Hm, the top level @ does influence how deep the destructuring goes (also the destructuring policy per class has a depth limit) - bottom line is I think what you're seeing is what happens when it reaches the max destructuring depth (I'd google on `serilog depth limit destructuring` or similar).

Comment: I'm using ForContext(), so the object it isn't in the message itself. The default depth is 5, and this is only the second level, so Serilog shouldn't be limiting it itself. I tried manually setting it to five. I wasn't sure if order was important, so I set it on either side of Destructure.With<>() call, but it still was turned into a string. I wonder if the issue is with Serilog.Enrichers.Context. Could that somehow cause depth to be ignored?

Comment: Right, that's why you need to show what you're doing! I _think_ (but am not sure!) had a similar issue - wanting to [inhibit the default limiting for a contextual value](https://github.com/jet/equinox/blob/master/src/Equinox.EventStore/EventStore.fs#L41) - note this can also be achieved by configuring the destructuring rules for the type of the object you're including

Comment: I added some code that I tried. I'm wondering if the problem is the EventFlow interface. The code in https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow.Inputs.Serilog/SerilogInput.cs looks OK, but I'm not positive that it isn't flattening out my StructureValue.

Comment: wild guess: can you step into and/or place breakpoints to figure out if the impl is [doing what it suggests, to your cost? ](https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow.Inputs.Serilog/SerilogInput.cs#L128-L129)

Comment: Yes, it is the EventFlow Serilog code. Instead of ToRawValue() recursively calling itself, it calls ToRawScalar(), forcing Serilog to have only one level. :-(

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update this post. They added a new property "ignoreSerilogDepthLevel" that defaults to true, to preserve original behavior. Now I can set this to false and it will destructure using SeriLog's configured depth.